# Trying to show set of decimals with only $4$s and $7$s is compact using a different method

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be the set of $x\in I$ where $I$ is the unit interval $[0,1]$ with decimal expansion $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{10^n}$, and $a_n\in\{4,7\}$. I want to show this is compact using a different approach to the canonical one of constructing explicit epsilon balls around elements in the complement. Here is my idea:

Clearly $A$ is bounded above and below since $A\subseteq[0,1]$. It suffices to show then that $A$ is closed. We do this by showing that $A^c$ is open. Take $x\in A^c$. If $x<0.\bar{4}$, then take the open set $(0,0.\bar{4})$. If $x>0.\bar{7}$, then take the open set $(0.\bar{7},1)$. Now, we consider the case where $x\in(0.\bar{4},0.\bar{7})\cap A^c$. We consider the set $Y$ of $y\in A$ such that $y<x$ and the set $Z$ of $z\in A$ such that $z>x$. By least upper bound property of the real numbers (since these two sets are non-empty), we have that they have a $\sup$ and $\inf$ respectively. Therefore, take the open set $(\sup{Y},\inf{Z})$.

> My problem is that I don't know if we can guarantee that $x\neq\sup{Y}$ and $x\neq\inf{Z}$. Is there a way to remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a sequence of points $(x_n)$ in $A$ such that $x_n \to \sup Y$. Similarly for $\inf Z$. So it suffices to show that no sequence in $A$ can converge to $x$.

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges. So in particular there exists $N$ such that for all $n,m>N$, $|x_n-x_m|<0.1$. Since the digits of $x_n$ and $x_m$ can only be $4$ and $7$, this implies that the first digit of both must be the same (otherwise their difference would be $>0.1$ since the closest two numbers in $A$ that differ in their first digit are $0.4777\dots$ and $0.7444\dots$). Since this holds for all $n,m>N$, this implies the first digit of the sequence $(x_n)$ is eventually constant (either $4$ or $7$).

Similarly, there exists $N'$ such that for all $n,m>N'$, $|x_n-x_m|<0.01$. Again, the digits of $x_n$ and $x_m$ can only be $4$ and $7$, so this implies that eventually the first two digits of both must be the same. So once again, the first two digits of $(x_n)$ are eventually constant.

You can extend this argument to show that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the first $k$ digits of the sequence $(x_n)$ must be eventually constant. Now if $\sup Y=x$, so that $x_n \to x$, this would imply that the first $k$ digits of $x$ must be the same as the eventual first $k$ digits of the sequence $(x_n)$. You must argue this carefully using the fact that the $x_n$'s only have $4$ and $7$ as their digits - it is not true, for instance, for the sequence $(0.9,0.99,0.999,\dots)$ that converges to $1.0$. Once you have shown this, though, you have reached a contradiction because this implies that for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the first $k$ digits of $x$ are all in $\{4,7\}$, so in fact all digits of $x$ are in $\{4,7\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the set where the $k$'th digit can be $4$ or $7$ (allowing infinite strings of $9$'s) is the union of finitely many closed intervals.